# Save traceback on error using tryCatch

Tags: r, stack-trace, cran

When calling an R function inside my webapp, I would like to catch the stack-trace when an error occurs and present it to the user for debugging purposes. Something like the output of `traceback()` in an interactive session. However, `traceback` doesn't seem to work when it is called inside the error handler, it returns `No traceback available`:

```
f <- function() {
    g <- function() stop("test traceback")
    g()
}

errhandler <- function(e){
  stacktrace <- traceback()
  unlist(stacktrace);
}

out <- tryCatch(f(), error=errhandler)
```

Is there any way I can programatically catch the stack trace of an error? I.e. get the output that I would get when calling `traceback()` manually after the error:

```
f()
traceback()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the latest version of the `evaluate` package has a function called `try_capture_stack` which is a pretty [good implementation](https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/blob/master/R/traceback.r) of this.

Comment: What are the bad side-effects of using .try_quietly?

Answer (score 2):

The function `tools:::.try_quietly` does something similar:

```
f <- function() {
  g <- function() stop("test traceback")
  g()
}

tools:::.try_quietly(f()) 

Error: test traceback
Call sequence:
3: stop("test traceback")
2: g()
1: f()
```

However, the errors and warnings are printed to `outConn` using `sink()` - this means you can't directly assign the results to an object.  To work around this, you may have to change the code to use `print()` instead of `sink` (*untried*).

Comment: I found this one as well, but it has many nasty side effects and doesn't play nice with `tryCatch`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get a stack as with traceback with `try_capture_stack`, so I wrote a solution that works like `try`, except that it also returns the call stack. `tools:::.try_quietly` is neat, but does not save the stacks for later inspection...

```
tryStack <- function(
expr,
silent=FALSE
)
{
tryenv <- new.env()
out <- try(withCallingHandlers(expr, error=function(e)
  {
  stack <- sys.calls()
  stack <- stack[-(2:7)]
  stack <- head(stack, -2)
  stack <- sapply(stack, deparse)
  if(!silent && isTRUE(getOption("show.error.messages"))) 
    cat("This is the error stack: ", stack, sep="\n")
  assign("stackmsg", value=paste(stack,collapse="\n"), envir=tryenv)
  }), silent=silent)
if(inherits(out, "try-error")) out[2] <- tryenv$stackmsg
out
}

lower <- function(a) a+10
upper <- function(b) {plot(b, main=b) ; lower(b) }

d <- tryStack(upper(4))
d <- tryStack(upper("4"))
cat(d[2])
```

More info in my answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899766/1587132

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer to this specific question here, and provide the link for reference. This also goes for the other answers you have added recently.