# Some function arguments are not available in debugger() when examining the dump.frames()'s dump

Tags: r

I am trying to save a complete dump which allows a good debugging, but I found that some function arguments (e.g. those which are evaluated from global environment), are not saved. I created a simplified example to illustrate this:

```
covariates <- c("hi", "there", "user")

f <- function (covariates, double_x) 
{
    stop("HI, ERROR!")
}

g <- function (x)
{
    f(covariates, 2*x)
}

options(warn = 1, keep.source = TRUE, show.error.locations = TRUE, error = quote({
    cat("\n====================\nERROR HANDLING ROUTINE\n")
    dump.frames(dumpto = "last.dump", to.file = TRUE, include.GlobalEnv = TRUE)
}))

g(100)
```

Now, when I am later examining the dump **(in a different interactive R session**

- important!), you can see that everything looks fine, but the `covariates` argument of function is not found:

  > load("last.dump.rda")
  > debugger(last.dump)
  > Message:  Error in f(covariates, 2 * x) : HI, ERROR!
  > Available environments had calls:
  > 1: .GlobalEnv
  > 2: g(100)
  > 3: #3: f(covariates, 2 * x)
  > 4: #3: stop("HI, ERROR!")

  Enter an environment number, or 0 to exit  Selection:
  Selection: 3
  Browsing in the environment with call:
  #3: f(covariates, 2 * x)
  Called from: debugger.look(ind)
  Browse[1]> ls()
  [1] "double_x"
  Browse[1]> double_x
  [1] 200
  Browse[1]> covariates
  Error: object 'covariates' not found

In the end, the `covariates` variable can be found in the first frame `1: .GlobalEnv`; but **why is `covariates` not available in the frame of function `f`, when it is its argument, thus local to function `f`**? This complicates the debugging a lot...  Is there another way to fix it? I am little bothered that this doesn't the same way as the `options(error = recover)` in the interactive session.

PS: this question is inspired by [this answer showing a nice way how to track errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000757/684229).

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Both variables return values for me. What version of R are you using? I used R3.6.1.

Comment: @MrFlick really? That's interesting! I am using R 3.6.1. too!

Comment: But @MrFlick, do you start a new R session for the debugger? If do it in the same, it is obvious that it will work... I am interested in post mortem analysis of the dump file, when the original R session with the error is no longer running.

Comment: Ah. I restarted R in RStudio but I didn't realize it was auto-reloading the workspace. I now get the same behavior. But I'm more surprised that `double_x` is there than that `covariates` is not from this blurb on the `dump.frames` help page: "Note that not all the information in the original frame will be available, e.g. promises which have not yet been evaluated and the contents of any ... argument." If I had a `force()` to those values before the `stop()`, then they are both there.